# Python Selenium - How to loop to the last <li> element in a site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have created a python selenium script that should navigate through a website and collect people profiles (https://www.shearman.com/people). The program won't loop through the pages to collect the links. I have used this which doesn't work;

```
 try:
     # this is navigate to next page
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="searchResultsSection"]/ul/li[12]').click()
     time.sleep(1)
 except NoSuchElementException:
     break
```

The syntax behind the next button can be seen below;

```
<a href="" onclick="PageRequest('2', event)" class="xh-highlight">&gt;</a>
```

Does anybody no how to write the code to click the next button?

Comment: Why? This is morally questionable at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the *HTML* of the element with image as **`>`**, it is the `<a>` tag within the last `<li>` tag of the `<ul>` tag. So to invoke `click()` on it you can use the following code block :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='results-pagination']/li[last()]/a").click()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can do it yourself :

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
- right click on the next button -> inspect
- right click on the next button code -> copy -> copy selector

then you store the button in a WebElement nextButton then

```
nextButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use below line to click Next button

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(">").click()
```